# Protractor Drag and Drop In SVG Element

Tags: protractor

I am facing the problem in drag and drop the element to one editor page and editor page is SVG element. I am using this code, but it is not working

```
var dragAndDrop = require('html-dnd').code;
var dragDataType=element(By.id('{"name":"Filter","type":"Filter","icon":"filter_list","iconHex":"&#xE152;"}'));
var dropDataType= element(By.id('___content'));
var offsetX = 1;
var offsetY = 1;
var offsetX = 300;
var offsetY = 250;
browser.executeScript(dragAndDrop, dragDataType, dropDataType, offsetX,offsetY);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented drag and drop like this:

```
 xxxx.protorype.dragNDrop= function(){
  var offsetx = <offsetValueX>;
  var offsety = <offsetValueY>;
  this.getDropIndex(dragElement, function (dropIndex) {
    var dropElement = element(<locator>).get(dropIndex);
    dropElement.getLocation().then(function (location) {
      offsetx = Math.round(offsetx + location.x);
      browser.actions().mouseMove(dragElement)
        .mouseDown()
        .mouseMove(dropElement)
        .mouseMove(dropElement, {x: offsetx, y: offsety})
        .mouseUp().perform();
    });
    browser.waitForAngular();
    expect(element(<your locator>).getAttribute()).toBe(dragElement.getAttribute());
  });
  };

  xxxx.prototype.getDropIndex = function (elementHolder, callback) {
  browser.waitForAngular();
  elementHolder.getText().then(function (elementName) {
  var index;
    if (callback) {
      callback(index);
    }
  });
};
```

Here it is done using the browser.actions(), since there is not in build function. I have used like this.